# Solution to lack of conditional formatting by row?

Tags: powerbi, heatmap, conditional-formatting

[image: Example]

I have a wide variety of data in a matrix that I need to be able to visually analyze on a row-by-row basis as per the above.  Unfortunately, there does not seem to be an option to do this yet with the Matrix visual.  I took a look on the marketplace but could find a quick solution.  Has anyone been able to work around this limitation?  I saw the % of total row option but this is not ideal for also displaying the data.

---

**EDIT for @Alexis feedback 6/26/2018:**

Formula I am using:

```
AGP% Color by Series = 

VAR MaxVal  = MAXX(SUMMARIZE(ALLEXCEPT(MonthlyReporting, MonthlyReporting[SERIES]), MonthlyReporting[InvoiceDate].[Month], "Monthly", [AGP%]), [Monthly])

VAR MinVal = MINX(SUMMARIZE(ALLEXCEPT(MonthlyReporting, MonthlyReporting[SERIES]), MonthlyReporting[InvoiceDate].[Month], "Monthly", [AGP%]), [Monthly])

RETURN DIVIDE([AGP%] - MinVal, MaxVal - MinVal)
```

I actually understand most of the above formula except for the clauses ...""Monthly", [AGP%]), [Monthly])" - what are these doing?

Results I am getting:

2018 Only - seems to be working, but lack of a complete spectrum on each row leads me to believe that ALLEXCEPT logic is incomplete:
[image: 2018 Only]

2017 and 2018 - this is a big mess - possibly caused in part by that outlier:
[image: 2017 and 2018]

Semi-related, how did you end up getting so good at DAX?  Would love to be able to build my own proficiency; certainly going to fully dissect this solution in order to better learn.  Are there any specific courses, books or resources that ended up giving you a jumpstart?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are asking. Can you give an example of what you would like your matrix to look like?

Comment: Sorry Alexis, I added an example above.

Comment: Regarding your last question, I got good mostly by building reports and answering questions on here. I've also read and would recommend the Definitive Guide to DAX by Russo and Ferrari. (FYI, the 2nd edition comes out Aug 6, 2018.)

Comment: awesome, have this on order (2nd edition)

Answer (score 2):

The matrix visual does allow for conditional formatting, but applying this to the value in the cells will apply the formatting to all cells using the same range, which looks something like this.

[image: Bad Coloring]

However, in the May update to Power BI desktop allows [conditional formatting by a different field](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-desktop-may-2018-feature-summary/#conditionalFormatting). Thus we can write a measure that calculates values ranges by row and use that measure in the conditional formatting.

```
Color =
    VAR MaxVal = CALCULATE(MAX(Table2[Value]), ALL(Table2[Month]))
    VAR MinVal = CALCULATE(MIN(Table2[Value]), ALL(Table2[Month]))
    RETURN DIVIDE(MAX(Table2[Value]) - MinVal, MaxVal - MinVal)
```

This `Color` measure is a linear interpolation between the max and min values that occur for that customer over all months. If we use this measure in the conditional formatting like so:

[image: Conditional Formatting]

Then the result should be pretty close to your desired coloring.

[image: Good Coloring]

---

**Edit**: If the values you have in the table are based on a measure, then you'll need to adjust the `Color` measure accordingly.

```
Color = 
    VAR MaxVal = MAXX(SUMMARIZE(ALLEXCEPT(Table2, Table2[Customer]), Table2[Month], "Monthly", [Measure]), [Monthly])
    VAR MinVal = MINX(SUMMARIZE(ALLEXCEPT(Table2, Table2[Customer]), Table2[Month], "Monthly", [Measure]), [Monthly])
    RETURN DIVIDE([Measure] - MinVal, MaxVal - MinVal)
```

Comment: thank you again for your help so far!  I am running into an issue with the MAX() formula - it seems to specifically want a column reference, however because I am analyzing gross profit margin, it is necessary to provide a measure instead (otherwise the AGP on a line level is not statistically relevant given the AGP$ of each line varies).  Is there something else I should be using here instead of MAX()?  Also tried to recalculate the AGP% measure within the MAX() formula and it does not like that either.

Comment: OK, so this gets me a lot closer but not quite there.  Two results below, one looking at 2018, and one looking at 2017 and 2018.  

Here is the formula that I am presently using.  

AGP% Color by Series = VAR MaxVal  = MAXX(SUMMARIZE(ALLEXCEPT(MonthlyReporting, MonthlyReporting[SERIES]), MonthlyReporting[InvoiceDate].[Month], "Monthly", [AGP%]), [Monthly])
    VAR MinVal = MINX(SUMMARIZE(ALLEXCEPT(MonthlyReporting, MonthlyReporting[SERIES]), MonthlyReporting[InvoiceDate].[Month], "Monthly", [AGP%]), [Monthly])
    RETURN DIVIDE([AGP%] - MinVal, MaxVal - MinVal)

Comment: ugh I am going to edit the OP instead, these comments don't seem to format very well

Comment: Do you have a PBIX file you can share? Getting the filters just right is tricky to do when I can't see all your relationships and hierarchies. If your data is sensitive, can you create an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Yeah I can get you a trimmed PBIX today.  What is the preferred method of delivery here / for you?

Comment: Dropbox or Google Docs or something similar.

Comment: Alexis, sorry for delay on this; got dragged into a project.  I am working on a trimmed PBIX still, would prefer to be able to get it to you in some form of secured format such as e-mail vs posting a link here, let me know if that is possible.

Comment: You can use FirstnameLastname@gmail.com (using my name) to reach me via email.

Comment: thank you, will send you something in next 1-2 days, will post solution in this thread